# How to get form params in controller when using foreach in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have two models, 'Question' and 'QuestionChoice'. A 'Question' has_many 'QuestionChoices'. I am using each loop in a form in my view to get data from the user. A question with choices are presented for the user using collection_select and the user has to choose the correct answer. The problem is that I only get the last params value in controller. I couldn't figure out a way to get all params from my each loop.

View:

```
<%= form_with(url: "/home/result", method: "get") do |f| %>
    <% @question.each do |question| %> <br />
        <%= question.question %> <br />
        <%= f.collection_select(:choice_id, QuestionChoice.where(question_id: question.id), :choice, :choice) %> <br />
    <%end %>
    <br />
    <%= f.submit("Complete Assignment") %>
<%end %>
```

I need to get all choices values that user selects for all questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `QuestionChoice` in the controller you are calling with `Question` therefor you can play around with the loop.

Comment: I still could not figure it out. I has to use loop doesn't matter if in view or controller. collection_select only passes the selected value of last QuestionChoice in params.